# Laravel ErrorException Undefined offset: 0 when adding Route::Auth();

Tags: php, laravel

I can not use: `php artisan make:auth`

so I use the following commands:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan migrate
npm install
npm run dev
```

Web.php:

```
   Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::Auth();;


Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Then it happens that the index stops working and sends the error: `Laravel ErrorException Undefined offset: 0`

if I document the line `Route::Auth();` in web.php the index is back online but without the option to login or register

What is the error that prevents `Auth` from running?

Comment: The routes method for ui is `Auth::routes();` not `Route::auth()`

Comment: if I use Auth :: routes (); I get: Undefined type 'Auth'.intelephense (1009)

Comment: By default \Auth is registered as an alias if you are still having problems try importing \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Answer (score 0):

You wrote Route::Auth() with capital 'A' it's Route::auth();
In laravel v<=5.1 it's "Auth::routes();"